# the_tags without hyperlinks?

Tags: theme-development

How can I call the_tags as a list without hyperlinks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ul>
   <?php
    $tags = get_tags();

    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        echo "<li>$tag->name</li>";
   }
   ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Are there any other methods that will return the post tags with a separator and no links?

Comment: This is the only one that I know of. All other functions return tags as links. You could always write your own function. :)

Answer (score 3):

It shows the tags of your post. If you use "get_tags()" you will list all tags of wordpress.

```
   <?php
    if (is_array(get_the_tags())) {
           $tags = get_the_tags();
           foreach($tags as $tag) {
              echo "$tag->name";
           } 
        } 
    ?>
```

You should check the get_the_tags() if "is_array()" or you'll get error case the_post() doesn't have a tag .